# problem in using emmet in visual studio code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, jsx, emmet

I am experiencing a strange problem with emmet in vs code.
after typing some emmet abbreviation and pressing tab I get a warning saying "command `emmet.expandAbbriviation` not found"
I have double-checked my `settings.json` and `"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true` is there in the file.
I have been using vs code for a month but never before I had any problem with emmet, but suddenly this problem has come up

Update: I have noticed that suddenly other extensions like live server have also stopped working and also I'm no longer getting autocomplete suggestions from MDN docs.

Answer (score 3):

Judging from this [emmet won't work issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/123388), the problem might have begun as a result of the last update.

Search `@builtin` in the Extensions view and make sure the Emmet extension is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the VS Code. Go to the Vscode settings by pressing the setting icon or ctrl+.
2. In the setting tabs, click on the HTML option.
3. Click on the “Edit in settings:json” hyperlink to edit the settings in JSON format. Click on the Edit in settings.json to edit and fix emmet problems.
4. Inside the curly braces, enter the following code under the already written JSON code:

“emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab”: true,
“files.associations”: {“*html”: “html”}

5.Save the file. Now if you try to apply emmet in your code, it will work smoothly!!

Comment: thanks for your help but this does not work

Answer (score 0):

Because the error you are reporting reads like this:

> "command emmet.expandAbbriviation not found"

You may have a typo in that command which would explain the interpreters inability to find the command. Of course it could be that you have the typo here in this post while your settings in VS Code are correct.

Either way, the correct spelling is **`emmet.expandAbbreviation`**. Notice the letter before the 'v' is an 'e' not an 'i'.

Answer (score 0):

This link here seems to have the same issue..

[VS Code - command 'emmet.expandAbbreviation' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67587366/vs-code-command-emmet-expandabbreviation-not-found/67954410#67954410)

I had the same issue as well and could not find much help..

But what fixed it for me was using a previous version.. so something with the never version might not work with my settings I guess (and some them I can't change like my Mac OS..;-).. as my mac is 2015 edition).. Anyways if you are still having this issue.. this link is what worked for me..

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_55

Download an earlier version and you should be fine... Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I added a `vetur.config.js` file to my root directory, and it is working fine.

I can tab as per normal. HTML autocomplete is also back.

got the reference here:
https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/reference/#example