# VS Code - command 'emmet.expandAbbreviation' not found

Tags: visual-studio-code

Emmet Abbreviations are not working for me in VS Code. I looked up solutions, and added `"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true` to my settings.json file.

When I added it, every time I pressed tab to indent it says "command 'emmet.expandAbbreviation' not found".

It stops showing that once I remove the line.

Additionally, there is no syntax coloring or suggestions in HTML files. I tried to fix it by adding `"files.associations": {"*.html": "html"}` but that didn't work either.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Try the fix in https://stackoverflow.com/a/67506047/836330 and see if it helps.

Answer (score 8):

I had this issue too, but I simply restarted VS Code and that actually solved the problem!

Comment: this worked! love it when the fix is that easy.

Answer (score 2):

I simply commented out `"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true` then it started working.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as well and could not find much help.. but what fixed it for me was using a previous version.. so something with the never version might not work with my settings I guess (and some them I can't change like my Mac OS..;-).. as my mac is 2015 edition).. Anyways if you are still having this issue.. this link is what worked for me..

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_55

Download an earlier version and you should be fine...

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot of different things (including re-installing vscode) I got desperate, disabled all of my extensions, reloaded vscode, and then reinstalled my key extensions. I didn't figure out which extension may have been causing the problem, but that did get it working again.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by re-enabling the emmet extension again. Not sure when it has been disabled.

Open the built-in extensions explorer (direct command: `Extensions: Show Built-in Extensions`), scroll down to find the emmet extension. For me it was disabled, and I had to open the context menu and click `Enabled`.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this problem after a VS Code update. I searched for disabled extensions and saw that, to my surprise, some 2/3 of my extensions have been disabled. I manually enabled one which seems to have triggered something because within seconds all these extensions (except those I actually had disabled some time ago) were live again.